# My BuffaloNAS LS-QVL stuck at Resyncing RAID

Tags: linux, raid, nas, raid-5, buffalo-nas

My BuffaloNAS LS-QVL 4bay / 1bay per 1TB lost raid5

so I try perform Check disk and then web ui stuck at page : "Checking drive... Progress: Progress" Since 9 Nov 2021 13:14:23

and then in the NAS Navigator2 Said 3 Messages

1.E14: RAID array 1 could not be mounted.

2.I12: The RAID array is in degraded mode.

3.I14: Resyncing RAID array 1... Since 9 Nov 2021 13:14:23

So this mean I have to wait the process to complete? and is it normal that in web ui there is no Progress percentage at all?

Comment: http://forums.buffalotech.com/index.php?topic=25015.0 this Dave guy says it can take 10 hours per TB.... Oxygen8 says: "You can check the status -- scroll to the right corner"

Comment: Thank You! Gantendo, before I post here I posted on BuffaloTech Forum and already read the same post. but I can't find any percentage because I can't access non of the menu above. but thank your for your help :)